# VB find and replace in excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using VB to populate data in excel. They are populating in column A, row 1 to 3000.

Here's a sample portion:

```
H'03F8
H'03FD
H'4404
H'0812
... and so on
```

Now what I want to do is to find all strings starting with H' and remove all occurrences of it in the sheet. So the result would be like:

```
03F8
03FD
4404
0812
... and so on
```

For this here is the code I'm using:

```
Dim xl = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
Dim sheet = wb.ActiveSheet

Private Sub find_replace()
    Dim myRange As Range
    myRange = sheet.Range("A1:A3000")
    For Each row In myRange
        sheet.substitute(myRange, "H'", "")
    Next

End Sub
```

But it gives an error while running: MissingMemberExeception was unhandled. and in the details it shows: Public member 'substitute' on type 'Worksheet' not found.

I'm using VB 2010 Express. Please help.

Comment: Why dont use use the simple Find & Replace funtion in Excel..(CTRL + H)

Comment: Since you are filling the excel sheet yourself with some VB.Net code, wouldn't it be easier to not write `H'` into the sheet in the first place?

Comment: Thanks Dominic for making me think in that way. Got it working like you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the following VBA:

```
sheet.Range("A1", "A3000").Replace "H'", "'"
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. I need a little more of your help though. When entries such as `H'03E8` are encountered, after running the this code the left-out should be `3E8`, but for some reason they are coming as `3.00E+08`. Help me out please.

Comment: I'm updating my answer. Please verify if this helps.

Comment: This modification will add the unwanted `'` in front front of each entry. I fixed this issue by adding this line of code `sheet.Range("A1", "A3000").NumberFormat = "@"` which sets the cell format as text thereby retaining the `03E8` value. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
Private Sub find_replace()
    Dim myRange, r As Range
    Dim s As String

    myRange = sheet.Range("A1:A3000")
    For Each r In myRange
        s = r.Value            
        r.Value = s.Substitute("H'", "" )
    Next

End Sub
```